how to auto login after signUp using Auth.php in Laravel11
Auth.php
<?php

return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'web'),
        'passwords' => env('AUTH_PASSWORD_BROKER', 'use_accounts'),
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'use_accounts',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'use_accounts' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
        ],

       
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'use_accounts' => [
            'provider' => 'use_accounts',
            'table' => env('AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET_TOKEN_TABLE', 'password_reset_tokens'),
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],


    'password_timeout' => env('AUTH_PASSWORD_TIMEOUT', 10800),

];


Controller
 public function signUp(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $user = new UseAccount;
        $user->name= $request->name;
        $user->email= $request->email;
        $user->password= $request->password;
        $user->save();

        $credential = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ];
        if(Auth::attempt([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ])){
            return redirect('home');
        }
        }
        return view('auth.signUp');
    }

Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct(): Argument #2 ($provider) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in W:\Software House\task_Management\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 127
